# Is it possible to use @googleapis/gmail without installing the entire googleapis dependency?

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

The @googleapis/gmail dependency can be installed by itself, but there is one line I can't get to work without installing the greater googleapis dependency, from the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), it's the call to get the oauth client:

`const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});`

Does getting the authorized client require the entire googleapis package be installed or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#:%7E:text=you%20can%20alternatively%20install%20a%20submodule%20as%20its%20own%20dependency), yes, you can make calls directly to the API by installing a submodule, in this case `@googleapis/gmail`. You can see this [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#:%7E:text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20can%20make%20calls%20directly%20to%20the%20APIs%20by%20installing%20a%20submodule%3A) on how to make calls when installing a submodule. You can also try installing the [Google Auth Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#google-auth-library-nodejs-client) `npm install google-auth-library`